# Java Using strings from within a switch statement

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I have the following code

```
    switch (dayCurrent) {
        case 0: 
                String today_sun = "Today is Sunday";
                break;
        case 1: 
                String today_mon = "Today is Monday";
                break;
        case 2: 
                String today_tues = "Today is Tuesday";
                break;
        case 3: 
                String today_wed = "Today is Wednesday";
                break;
        case 4: 
                String today_thurs = "Today is Thursday";
                break;
        case 5: 
                String today_fri = "Today is Friday";
                break;
        case 6: 
                String today_sat = "Today is Saturday";
                break;
        // If statement for invalid entry
        default: if (dayCurrent >= 7) {
            System.out.println("Invalid day entered");
        }
    }
    // Switch statements to display future day
    if (dayCurrent < 7) {
        switch (dayFinal) {
            case 0: 
                    String future_sun = dayFuture + " day(s) later it is Sunday";
                    break;
            case 1: 
                    String future_mon = dayFuture + " day(s) later is Monday";
                    break;
            case 2: 
                    String future_tues = dayFuture + " day(s) later is Tuesday";
                    break;
            case 3: 
                    String future_wed = dayFuture + " day(s) later is Wednesday";
                    break;
            case 4: 
                    String future_thurs = dayFuture + " day(s) later is Thursday";
                    break;
            case 5: 
                    String future_fri = dayFuture + " day(s) later is Friday";
                    break;
            case 6: 
                    String future_sat = dayFuture + " day(s) later is Saturday";
                    break;
```

If I wanted to create a System.out.println that showed the results of both switches, how would I go about doing this?
I know this code appeared here before: [Java (Find the future date with if else statements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993698/java-find-the-future-date-with-if-else-statements) , and that it would be easier to do System.out.print, but I'm curious on how to do the above for future reference.

Comment: Why don't you put  sysout statements within your switch cases

Comment: what is the point of having variables being declared in the `case` blocks.  They will be limited in scope to these blocks (i.e. not visible to outside of these blocks of code).  What is dayFuture and where is in defined.  Why not do simple int arithmetic?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this site. I tried putting in my entire code and it didn't translate well so I cut it out.

Comment: Declare `String today;` and `String future;` before the switch statements and assign those variables in the case 'blocks'. Then `System.out.println(today) ` and `future` after the switch statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Concatenation

When piecing together multiple strings across your code, concatenate them. There are multiple ways to do this in Java.

The `+` sign combines `String` objects. Each `String` object is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), meaning you to do not change (“mutate”) its value. Instead a new instance is born combining the original value and the newly added String object.

```
String message = "My name is ";
message = message + "Basil";
message = message + "."; 
System.out.println( message );  // My name is Basil.
```

Another way is to call [`append`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html#append-java.lang.CharSequence-) on an object of any class that implements the [`Appendable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) interface.

[`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is the `Appendable` implementation appropriate to your situation.

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder( "My name is " );
message.append( "Basil" );
message.append( "." ); 
System.out.println( message.toString() );  // My name is Basil.
```

Caveat: Use `StringBuilder` only where [thread-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) is not a problem. When your `Appendable` object may be accessed across more than one thread, use [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead.

For more information on the various kinds of string-related objects with a nifty chart to make sense of them, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26498954/642706) to the Question, [Exact difference between CharSequence and String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11323962/642706).

## `DayOfWeek`

The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) holds seven instances, one for each day of the week. Getting today’s day-of-week means getting today’s date, and that requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from( today );  // `dow` is an *object*, not mere text like `Monday` or mere integer number like `1`.
```

Using objects of this [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) rather than mere integers to represent a day-of-week makes your code more self-documenting, provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and ensures valid values.

## Define text object *outside* switch block

The main problem in the Question’s code is that the variable holding the String is defined *inside* the `switch` `case`; that variable goes out of scope upon exiting the `switch` `case`, and immediately becomes a candidate for [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) (your string object goes away and is destroyed, cleared from memory, in other words) before you ever got a chance to concatenate or print your text content.

So this code:

```
switch (dayCurrent) {
    case 0: 
            String today_sun = "Today is Sunday";
            break;
    case 1: 
            String today_mon = "Today is Monday";
            break;
…
```

…should have been:

```
String today = null;

switch (dayCurrent) {
    case 0: 
            today = "Today is Sunday";
            break;
    case 1: 
            today = "Today is Monday";
            break;
…
```

But, even better, we can replace that `String` object with an `Appendable`:  `StringBuilder`.

## `StringBuilder`

When concatenating more than a few strings, and thread-safety is not a problem in your context, use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class.

Note that we define this `StringBuilder` object named `message` *outside* the `switch` block. Defining outside the `switch` means the object survives, existing before, during, and after the switch does its job.

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

switch ( dow ) {
    case DayOfWeek.MONDAY:
    case DayOfWeek.TUESDAY: 
    case DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY: 
    case DayOfWeek.THURSDAY:  
    case DayOfWeek.FRIDAY: 
        message.append( "Weekday - Working for a living. " );
        break;

    case DayOfWeek.SATURDAY:
    case DayOfWeek.SUNDAY: 
        message.append( "Wohoo! Weekend… Party on Garth! " );
        break;

    default: 
        System.out.println("ERROR - Unexpectedly reached case DEFAULT on value for DayOfWeek 'dow'.");
    }
```

The `dayFuture` part of your code makes no sense to me, and seems irrelevant to your question of piecing together text across multiple `switch` blocks. So I will use a nonsense `whatever` switch.

```
switch ( whatever ) {
    case thisThing: 
        message.append( "Use vanilla." );
        break;

    case thatThing: 
        message.append( "Use chocolate." );
        break;

    case theOtherThing: 
        message.append( "Use almond." );
        break;

    default: 
        System.out.println("ERROR - Unexpectedly reached case DEFAULT on value for whatever.");
    }
```

Now we have built up a message made of multiple components. We can output that to [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out).

```
System.out.println( message.toString() ); // Outputs day-of-week text combined with flavor text.
```

> Weekday - Working for a living. Use chocolate.

## Date math

As for adding days to a date to get another date, simply call the `plus…` or `minus…` methods.

If the user inputs a String of digits, parse as a number for the count of days to add.

```
Integer days = Integer.valueOf( "4" );
```

Add that number of days.

```
LocalDate future = today.plusDays( days );
```

If passing around this elapsed time, use a `TemporalAmount` such as [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) or `Duration` object rather than mere integer.

```
Period period = Period.ofDays( days );
LocalDate future = today.plus( period );
```

To see that future date’s day-of-week, fetch a `DayOfWeek` enum object. No need for a switch.

```
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from( future );
```

You can ask the `DayOfWeek` for its localized name. Call [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-). Pass `TextStyle` to specify the length or abbreviation. And pass a `Locale` to specify the human language for translation and the cultural norms for deciding issues such as punctuation and ordering of the parts.

```
String dowName = 
    dow.getDisplayName( 
        TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , 
        Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't realize there was more than one way to perform concatenation. As for the dayFuture, the question asks us to input a value for both days and day's elapsed.

Comment: @NewProgrammerMR See the section I added, *Date math*.